# Почему в Qt при вводе пароля отображается флажок?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

В Qt 5.11 при вводе пароля положение курсора отображается с помощью флажка, а не черточки, как в обычных текстовых полях:

[image: пример]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Приведите ваш код. А так, я понимаю что у вас там QLineEdit с setEchoMode=QLineEdit::Password?

Comment: @gil9red да, именно так